# How to dissipate charge stored in a capacitor on demand

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic, capacitance

Building a 5V circuit board to switch on and off a 120V pump by means of a SSR with feedback to LEDs to indicate the system state - Pump On/Off and Temp High/Low.

Planning to measure the pump state using the AC output of the SSR instead of the 5V logic, to identify a failed SSR.  The 120V from SSR goes through a second 6 watt AC to DC power supply through an opticoupler and back to the logic to drive the LEDs.

The SSR turns off the pump and second power supply, but the capacitance in the power supply takes about 1 second to dissipate, resulting in the LEDs indicating the wrong system state during this time.

Is there a way to bleed the stored charge quickly after the SSR switches off?
Is there a better way to get the desired system state feedback?

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Is the load on the second power supply just the LEDs?  That may not draw much current, a pull-down resistor might be all you need.

Comment: I believe what @evildemonic is sayig is that a simple, always-connected, load resistor on your power supply output would more-quickly _drain away_ the resisdual energy in your AC-DC power supply after teh AC input is cut off.  That may work fine.  However keep in mind that the resistor should be rated properly for the power dissipated (as heat), and the power draw will be constant resulting in wasted energy.  Maybe use Neons instead of LEDs (no need for a DC supply then).  Maybe run the LED's off mains with a capacitor-dropper circuit (sketchy) or similar.

Comment: You should include more details like the rated power of your pump, at least a basic sketch if not a schematic of your arrangement, and possibly a picture of your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly you need to choose a power supply for the LED that does not store much energy,
for example reduce the capacitance in the power supply or increase the load on it.

Use a different indicator, for example a nightlight, a neon indicator, or a LED appliance lamp run at a reduced current.

Power the LED from a current transformer and bridge rectifier,
a 500:1 current transformer will get you 20mA worth of glow from a 10A load. If too much glow add a resistor in parallel.

Comment: I was just about to write a similar answer suggesting an opto-coupler with a series resistor voltage dropper or a current transformer when your answer popped up. :D

Comment: It's just to light an LED,  most indicators take the same sort of current as optocouplers.  just connect resistors and rectifier to the LED  add a light pipe if needed. no need tor an optocoupler,

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do what you need. Since you haven't included enough detail like the rated power of your pump and a sketch and a picture of your setup, my suggestions will be generic and you will have to figure out the details on your own.

1. First, you could use a plain resistor dropper in series with the pump motor, and then place an optocoupler across it, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNNsgp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The values of the resistors will depend on the motor current and the logic voltage levels. 
D1 and Q1 are actually an optocoupler.

2. You could use a current transformer or wind your own to give you about 1V on its output when the motor is running. You would place it instead of the R1 in my schematic.
3. You could use a resistor in series with the optocoupler and a high-voltage rectifying diode (at least 200V rating, to protect optocoupler from high reverse voltage) and place them across the motor. Since you don't need more than 1mA of current, a 120kΩ 1/4W would be sufficient, which is far more energy efficient than your current method. You could use a 150kΩ 1/2W resistor to use even less power and make sure it runs cooler and can withstand any voltage surges.
4. You could use a neon lamp in series with a 100kΩ 1/4W resistor and enclose it in a small dark case with a photo-resistor, photodiode or a photo-transistor which you would place instead of the Q1 in my circuit.
5. You could use setup similar to yours, but with a classic iron-core line-frequency, low power transformer (0.3VA to 3VA), a diode-bridge rectifier (or just a single diode, a high-resistance load resistor (like 10kΩ) in parallel with a 10uF capacitor.

These are only rough suggestions, specific values of resistors and capacitors likely need to be changed or experimented with.